# hash table with chaining within the table

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

I have this assignment to complete. (I am new to java). I started to think about it and establish a plan. I am not looking for the answers just a feedback on my approach.  I am supposed to enter integers into a hash table using a chaining scheme within the hash table (different from the regular chaining scheme).  My idea is to use an arraylist so I can store data + pointer in each slot of the hash table. when a collision occurs, find an empty slot, insert the new integer and set the pointer from the original hashed slot to this new position in the arraylist.  This way I am building a sort of linked list within the array. does that make sense?  there is a hint about keeping track of the free space with a stack... here I have to say I am not sure how to use the stack in that instance

Comment: try to implement it and see if it goes wrong, behaves badly, consume too much space, etc.

Comment: Try it out and see what happens. If you run into problems, post your question with the relevant code and stack trace here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

So prior to java8 hashmap internally will resolve collision using link list similar to your approach which brings the performance from O(1) to O(n) in case collision occurs, since java8 it is being handled via balanced tree which further improves the complexity to O(log n) in case of collision.
Your approach to use list is correct, but it comes to how you implement it.

Comment: thank you.  Here the goal, I think, is more about implementation rather than performance. At least I feel a little more confident about my approach. I will post my work if I have more question about implementation.